# How to extract list of values from JSON in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

In a SQL Server database, I have a table that contains 2 columns, `ID` and `JSON`. The `JSON` column contains JSON-formatted text. I have access to `ISJSON`, `JSON_VALUE` and `JSON_QUERY`, but not `OPENJSON`.

I am trying to write a query similar to the one below, that returns the ID column and all of the `WorkstationID` values. My query returns null. Can someone help me see what I am doing wrong?
Below is an example of the JSON data I am working with, as well as my query, and what I expect the output to look like. Thanks for any help that can be offered!

```json
{
   "areas":[
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[
            85,
            17,
            175,
            98
         ],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"592",
         "WorkstationID":"592"
      },
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[
            214,
            23,
            316,
            97
         ],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"594",
         "WorkstationID":"594"
      },
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[
            208,
            132,
            295,
            183
         ],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"595",
         "WorkstationID":"595"
      },
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[
            84,
            118,
            179,
            248
         ],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"596",
         "WorkstationID":"596"
      },
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[
            83,
            264,
            185,
            322
         ],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"597",
         "WorkstationID":"597"
      }
   ],
   "img":"/filepath/filename"
}
```

```sql
SELECT ID, JSON_QUERY(JSON,'$.areas') AS WorkstationID
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = 1
```

```
1,592
1,594
1,595
1,596
1,597
```

UPDATE:
As was discussed in the comments below, OPENJSON seems to be the easy way to do this, but this is not possible for me because my compatibility level is < 130. I have found that the following regex string can be used to extract all WorkstationID's from the JSON.

WorkstationID":"([0-9]{1,4})

Could using a regular expression like this be useful to return the list of all WorkstationID's contained in the JSON in a table format like what is explained in a table format?

Comment: Have a look at `OPENJSON`.

Comment: I think you might need `OPENJSON` in order to get all the vals in the array. Or else you have to use an explicit index. Why do you have access to all the other JSON functions, but not `OPENJSON`?

Comment: @dfundako can you give me an example of how I could use OPENJSON? I have tried working through several examples, but am struggling with the correct syntax.

Comment: When I try to use OPENJSON in SSMS, I get an error that says 'OPENJSON' is not a recognized built-in function name. Could I be getting this error because I am using the wrong syntax?

Comment: I discovered the reason I don't have access to OPENJSON, but I do have access to the other json functions is that OPENJSON requires the compatibility_level of the database be set to at least 130 (according to Microsoft docs), and the db I am using is set to 120, which I can't change. With this in mind, does anyone know how to solve my problem without using OPENJSON?

Comment: @Riggster: unnesting a JSON array without `OPENJSON()` makes things more complicated that they really need to. Any plans to increase the compatibility level of your server?

Comment: No, unfortunately increasing the compatibility level is not an option right now.

Comment: @Riggster How many rows in the table? Is this a 1 time thing or a recurring data pull?

Comment: This will be a one time thing. I just wrote a bug fix in an application, and now I need to fix some data that was messed up by the bug. I'll need to convert about 100 json strings to table format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this is a one-off for you, I've written an inefficient JSON to XML converter for you to access your data.

```
DECLARE @json varchar(8000) =
'{
   "areas":[
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[85, 17, 175, 98],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"592",
         "WorkstationID":"592"
      },
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[214, 23, 316, 97],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"594",
         "WorkstationID":"594"
      },
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[208, 132, 295, 183],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"595",
         "WorkstationID":"595"
      },
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[84, 118, 179, 248],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"596",
         "WorkstationID":"596"
      },
      {
         "type":"rect",
         "coords":[83, 264, 185, 322],
         "href":"#",
         "alt":"0",
         "title":"0",
         "nameid":"597",
         "WorkstationID":"597"
      }
   ],
   "img":"/filepath/filename"
}';

DECLARE @Fields table ( field varchar(50), tag varchar(50), term varchar(1), id int IDENTITY(1,1) );
INSERT INTO @Fields VALUES
    ( '"type":"', 'type', '"' ),
    ( '"coords":[', 'coords', ']' ),
    ( '"href":"', 'href', '"' ),
    ( '"alt":"', 'alt', '"' ),
    ( '"title":"', 'title', '"' ),
    ( '"nameid":"', 'nameid', '"' ),
    ( '"WorkstationID":"', 'WorkstationID', '"' ); 

-- Convert JSON to XML --
DECLARE @id int = 1, @field varchar(50), @tag varchar(50), @term varchar(1);
WHILE @id <= ( SELECT MAX ( id ) FROM @Fields )
BEGIN

    -- Current Field --
    SELECT 
        @field = field,
        @tag = tag,
        @term = term
    FROM @Fields WHERE id = @id;

    -- Convert field to XML --
    DECLARE @i int = CHARINDEX ( @field, @json );   
    WHILE @i > 0
    BEGIN
    
        -- Stuff in the opening tag --
        SELECT @json = STUFF (
            @json,
            CHARINDEX ( @field, @json, @i ),
            LEN ( @field ),
            '<' + @tag + '>'
        ),
        @json = STUFF (
            @json,
            CHARINDEX ( @term, @json, CHARINDEX ( @tag, @json, @i ) + 1 ),
            LEN ( @term ),
            '</' + @tag + '>'
        );

        -- Continue field search --
        SET @i = CHARINDEX ( @field, @json, @i );

    END

    -- Next Field --
    SET @id = @id + 1;

END

-- Final Cleanup --
SELECT
    @json = REPLACE ( @json, '{', '<data>' ),
    @json = REPLACE ( @json, '}', '</data>' ),
    @json = REPLACE ( @json, '"areas":[', '<areas>' ),
    @json = REPLACE ( @json, ']', '</areas>' ),
    @json = REPLACE ( @json, '"img":"/filepath/filename"', '<img>/filepath/filename</img>' ),
    @json = REPLACE ( @json, '>,', '>' );

-- Select resultset --
SELECT
    t.f.value( 'type[1]', 'varchar(255)' ) AS [type],
    t.f.value( 'coords[1]', 'varchar(255)' ) AS [coords],
    t.f.value( 'href[1]', 'varchar(255)' ) AS [href],
    t.f.value( 'alt[1]', 'varchar(255)' ) AS [alt],
    t.f.value( 'title[1]', 'varchar(255)' ) AS [title],
    t.f.value( 'nameid[1]', 'varchar(255)' ) AS [nameid],
    t.f.value( 'WorkstationID[1]', 'varchar(255)' ) AS [WorkstationID],
    t.f.value( '../../img[1]', 'varchar(255)' ) AS [img]
FROM (
    SELECT CAST ( @json AS xml ) AS d
) x
CROSS APPLY x.d.nodes('//data/areas/data') t(f);
```

Returns

```
+------+--------------------+------+-----+-------+--------+---------------+--------------------+
| type |       coords       | href | alt | title | nameid | WorkstationID |        img         |
+------+--------------------+------+-----+-------+--------+---------------+--------------------+
| rect | 85, 17, 175, 98    | #    |   0 |     0 |    592 |           592 | /filepath/filename |
| rect | 214, 23, 316, 97   | #    |   0 |     0 |    594 |           594 | /filepath/filename |
| rect | 208, 132, 295, 183 | #    |   0 |     0 |    595 |           595 | /filepath/filename |
| rect | 84, 118, 179, 248  | #    |   0 |     0 |    596 |           596 | /filepath/filename |
| rect | 83, 264, 185, 322  | #    |   0 |     0 |    597 |           597 | /filepath/filename |
+------+--------------------+------+-----+-------+--------+---------------+--------------------+
```

Your JSON gets converted to the following XML:

```
<data>
   <areas>
      <data>
         <type>rect</type>
         <coords>85, 17, 175, 98</coords>
         <href>#</href>
         <alt>0</alt>
         <title>0</title>
         <nameid>592</nameid>
         <WorkstationID>592</WorkstationID>
      </data>
      <data>
         <type>rect</type>
         <coords>214, 23, 316, 97</coords>
         <href>#</href>
         <alt>0</alt>
         <title>0</title>
         <nameid>594</nameid>
         <WorkstationID>594</WorkstationID>
      </data>
      <data>
         <type>rect</type>
         <coords>208, 132, 295, 183</coords>
         <href>#</href>
         <alt>0</alt>
         <title>0</title>
         <nameid>595</nameid>
         <WorkstationID>595</WorkstationID>
      </data>
      <data>
         <type>rect</type>
         <coords>84, 118, 179, 248</coords>
         <href>#</href>
         <alt>0</alt>
         <title>0</title>
         <nameid>596</nameid>
         <WorkstationID>596</WorkstationID>
      </data>
      <data>
         <type>rect</type>
         <coords>83, 264, 185, 322</coords>
         <href>#</href>
         <alt>0</alt>
         <title>0</title>
         <nameid>597</nameid>
         <WorkstationID>597</WorkstationID>
      </data>
   </areas>
   <img>/filepath/filename</img>
</data>
```